# Изменение атрибута src по клику

Tags: javascript

Есть коллекция img с блюр эффектом с атрибутами например `id="zero"` и `src="images/zeroblur.jpg"` как в примере ниже, есть также папка с такими же картинками но без блюр эффекта, по клику на картинку срабатывает Target, с его помощью мы получаем id и src каждой картинки по которой собственно кликаем, затем мы сравниваем значение атрибута "id" с "src", и если они не равны то путь в "src" меняется с `src="images/zeroblur.jpg"` на `src="images/zero.jpg"`, это дело работает, но вот когда опять кликаю, то путь не меняется обратно с `src="images/zero.jpg"` на `src="images/zeroblur.jpg"`.

```
<img id="zero" src="images/zeroblur.jpg" alt=""> // при клике путь меняется на src="images/zero.jpg" что совпадает с ID, но когда еще раз кликаю, то не меняется обратно на src="images/zeroblur.jpg"
<img id="one" src="images/oneblur.jpg" alt="">
<img id="two" src="images/twoblur.jpg" alt="">
<img id="three" src="images/threeblur.jpg" alt="">
<img id="four" src="images/fourblur.jpg" alt="">
<img id="five" src="images/fiveblur.jpg" alt="">



let getImg = document.querySelectorAll('img');    
for (let i = 0; i < getImg.length; i++) {
    getImg[i].onclick = function (objTarget) {
        let imgTarget = objTarget.target;
        let imgId = imgTarget.id;
        let imgSrc = imgTarget.src;

        if (imgId !== imgSrc) {
            imgId = "images/" + imgId + ".jpg";
            imgTarget.src = imgId;
        } else {
            imgId = "images/" + imgId + "blur.jpg";
            imgTarget.src = imgId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, `zero!==images/zero.jpg`. И никода не будет равен)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko действительно, не будут равны ))) а как тогда сообразить чтобы при повторном клике в src записывался путь как в else ?

Comment: Посмотрите функцию `indexOf`. Наверное, вам подойдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополнительный атрибут data-replace с самим изображением вместо id и заменяем значения в src при клике:

```js
let getImg = document.querySelectorAll('img');    
for (let i = 0; i < getImg.length; i++) {
    getImg[i].onclick = function (objTarget) {
        let imgTarget = objTarget.target;
        let imgClick = imgTarget.getAttribute('data-replace');
        let imgSrc = imgTarget.src;
        
        imgTarget.setAttribute('data-replace',imgSrc);
        imgTarget.setAttribute('src',imgClick);
        
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://hsto.org/storage2/152/5ee/fe4/1525eefe4cbeb0480e33bfcf1312b8f1.png" data-replace="https://hsto.org/storage2/d9e/e9b/89e/d9ee9b89eec2c4b25fadacd07e3c0438.png" alt="test">
```

Comment: а подскажите еще по поводу применения target тут, я попробовал убрать параметр в функции и переменную "imgTarget", и ниже где использовался "imgTarget" - заменил на this, работает также само, в чем разница тогда использовать через target или this ? по сути оба ссылаются на обьект над которым произошло событие